# What will you call someone who loves people of his own state within a country?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Is there any noun for a person who has special place/respect/love for people belonging to his own state within a country?

Answer (score 3):

> A patriot is a person who loves and zealously supports and defends their country.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patriot)

It is also used to show one's love and attachment to their own state.

> [Faulkner was a **Mississippi patriot** with a profound understanding of the historic injustices done black Americans but...](https://books.google.fr/books?id=b98t6YKdmCYC&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=%22a%20mississippi%20patriot%22&source=bl&ots=aco86z8nqc&sig=Dg79oQzOWw8gGe8o82YkrTqSLGQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYrdD75PrMAhXDWBoKHTsmDvoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20mississippi%20patriot%22&f=false)
>   (*Bye Bye, Miss American Empire: Neighborhood Patriots, Backcountry Rebels, and Their Underdog Crusades to Redraw America's Political Map*, by Bill Kauffman)

[Abraham Owen, a **Kentucky patriot** who sacrificed his life at the Battle of Tippecanoe in 1811.](http://www.owencohistory.com/History.html)

[It’s a rather touchingly nostalgic essay in regret by a **Kansas patriot** mourning that his fellow Kansans have been left behind by that same wonderful “history”...](http://spectator.org/39786_whats-matter-kansas/)

Google search on [Michigan patriot](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=a%20NeW%20york%20state%20Patriot&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&q=%22a%20michigan%20Patriot%22).

etc...

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with their own state within a country, though.

Comment: @stangdon This is certainly the term I would use for someone with a particular affinity for his/her state: *as good New Jersey patriots, they always have Bon Jovi in the rotation*, or *you can't expect a Michigan patriot like Uncle Frank to even consider a Toyota*.

Answer (score 3):

Something that I've seen used (and have used myself) is by saying that such a person is a **proud [insert state demonym here]**. For example, I'm from the state of Oregon. If I was to call myself "someone who loves the state of Oregon and the people of Oregon", I would say this:

> I am a proud Oregonian.

All the states have a demonym that can be used instead of "Oregonian".

EDIT: Of course, this can be used for states outside of the US, as @ColleenV mentioned in their comment.

Comment: Keep in mind that countries other than the US have states within them, like India.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, that's true. I was just using the US as an example.

Comment: I just got stuck on the definite article in "all **the** states" - it's probably true though that all states in the world have some way of referring to their residents.